# Vite 4.1.0 compiling and running dev server even if there is typescript error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-redux, vite

I recently started using Vite 4.1.0 to build my React-Redux project with typescript. As we know, typescript ensures that everything is 'typed' and has some type associated with it.

I am coding in Visual Studio Code, and this IDE clearly is pointing out that there is a typescript error (even showing red squiggly line), but Vite is just ignoring it and compiling the code and running it successfully.

Here is the example I am talking about.

**UserView.tsx**

```
import React from 'react'
import { useAppDispatch, useAppSelector } from '../../app/hooks'
import { fetchUserDetails, typeIntialState } from './userSlice'

export default function UserView() {

    const users = useAppSelector((state) => state.user)
    const dispatch = useAppDispatch()

    const getUsers = () => {
        dispatch(fetchUserDetails())
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Users</h1>
            {!users.isLoading && users.data.length ? (
                <ul>
                    {
                        users.data.map(user => (
                            <li key={user.id}>{user.email}</li>
                        ))

                    }
                </ul>
            ) : null}
            <button onClick={() => getUsers()}>Generate Users</button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

And this is the user slice file

**userSlice.ts**

```
import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice, PayloadAction } from "@reduxjs/toolkit"
import axios from "axios"

interface User {
    id: number,
    name: string
}

interface InitialState  {
    isLoading: boolean,
    data: User[],
    error: string
}

const initialState : InitialState = {
    isLoading: false,
    data: [],
    error: ''
}

export const fetchUserDetails = createAsyncThunk('user/fetchUserDetails', () => {
    return axios
            .get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
            .then((response) => response.data)
})


const userSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'user',
    initialState,
    reducers: {},
    extraReducers: (builder) => {
        builder.addCase(fetchUserDetails.pending, (state) => {
            state.isLoading = true
        }),
        builder.addCase(fetchUserDetails.fulfilled, (state, action : PayloadAction<User[]>) => {
            state.isLoading = false
            state.data = action.payload
            state.error = ''
            console.log(state.data)
        }),
        builder.addCase(fetchUserDetails.rejected, (state, action ) => {
            state.isLoading = false
            state.data = []
            state.error = action.error.message || "Something went wrong"
        })
    },
})

export default userSlice.reducer

export type typeIntialState = typeof initialState
```

Here, in my `userSlice.ts` file, I have the `User` interface, which takes in only 'id' and 'name' property. However, in `UserView.tsx`, I am accessing `user.email` which is NOT a property of `User` interface.

This is flagged down by IDE and shows red squiggly, but Vite just goes up and builds without throwing any error.

I have tried migrating the SAME code without Vite and it is throwing error as expected and not building.

So, my question is, how do I make Vite throw me error when typescript is violated.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Does this help? https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#transpile-only

Comment: I would also recommend updating vite itself, by doing this: `npm install vite@latest -D`

Answer (score 1):

Vite doesn't support typechecking TypeScript code, because it works by transpiling each module in isolation as per the [documentation](https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#transpile-only). This makes it impossible to properly typecheck the project as a whole.

After coming across this problem while working with Svelte, I have found that the [vite-plugin-checker](https://github.com/fi3ework/vite-plugin-checker) plugin for Vite works really well to provide type checking in Vite.

All I had to do was add the plugin in vite.config.ts:

```
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    checker({
      typescript: true,
    }),
    svelte(),
  ],
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to you to use the [vite-plugin-checker](https://vite-plugin-checker.netlify.app/)

- Step 1: `npm i vite-plugin-checker -D`
- Step 2: Change `vite.config.ts` import: `import checker from 'vite-plugin-checker'`
- Step 3: Add Typescript check to `plugins` like this:
  `checker({ typscript: true, }),`

See example config:

```
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import checker from "vite-plugin-checker";

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    checker({
      typescript: true,
    }),
    react(),
  ],
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit confusing when you come from a compiled language like C or Java but is what Typescript is supposed to do. At it's core the Typescript compiler does two things:

1. Generating Javascript code from your Typescript code
2. Checking the code for type errors

The compiler does both of those things independent from each other. This means that you can write Typescript code that has type errors and emits valid Javascript.

Example (copied from the excellent book "Effective Typescript" by Dan Vanderkam):

```
$ cat test.ts
let x = 'hello';
x = 1234;
$ tsc test.ts
test.ts:2:1 - error TS2322: Type '1234' is not assignable to type 'string'
2 x = 1234;
 ~
$ cat test.js
var x = 'hello';
x = 1234;
```

Comment: Okay, but I believe this does not answer the question. My question is, in Vite with ReactJS and typescript, even though there is an error from typescript, Vite is still compiling it and running it instead of throwing an error. Whereas without Vite, in normal ReactJS and typescript, it is throwing error as expected. So how do I make Vite throw error when there is a typescript error?

Comment: @SreenathHS Please see my answer for a step by step guide on how to add the plugin checker and how to add it to your Vite config file.